# MVC Partial View clearing scripts Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Project: Asp.NET Core 2.1

Working on a dashboard project that has a side nav that's divides into sub side's etc. On the right side there is a "main view" where the partial should be loaded, so when the partial is selected it should be rendered on the right-hand side.

I have accomplished all of this, but when I have 2 different views with some javascript that is equal, like a variable, I then get an error for redeclaring, this is because the last script loaded is still cached. Anyone knows how to attack this problem?

The variables for the partial are also declared in the file and not separate, have tried to separate also, but this didn't work.

Thinking about just not loading this Ajax, but I like the smoothness of it.

Example

View1:

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello View1</h1>
  <script>
  const myVar1 = 'Hello';
  </script>
<div>
```

View2:

```
<div>
  <h6>Hello View2</h6>
  <script>
  const myVar1 = 'Hello';
  </script>
</div>
```

Error:
redeclaration of myVar1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, either you rename your constants so they use **unique** names, or you change `const` to `var`.

Comment: Thank you, was thinking about this, but wanted to see if anyone knew another way to "wipe out" those who already were there.

Comment: That would *probably* have undesired consequences. Just let the client deal with GC. It is probably bad design to have two modules that may or may not interact with each other utilize the same variable names, especially if they are defined with `const`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a namespace. JavaScript doesn't use the namespace keyword. What is used instead is closures. You cannot control the variable names especially when it is not your code. Try this:

Example

View1:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello View1</h1>
    <script>
        var cl1 = (function(e){
            const myVar1 = 'closure 1'; // No public access.
            return {
                myVar1:myVar1, // Assign public access to cl1.myVar1.
                vname:function(){return myVar1; } // or assign it as a getter.
            };
        })();
    </script>
<div>
```

View2:

```
<div>
    <h6>Hello View2</h6>
    <script>
        var cl2 = (function(){
            const myVar1 = 'closure 2';
            return {
                myVar1:myVar1,
                vname:function(){return myVar1; }
            };
        })();
    </script>
</div>
```

Test the output:

```
  <script>
    console.log('cl1.myVar1', cl1.myVar1, cl1.vname());
    console.log('cl2.myVar1', cl2.myVar1, cl2.vname());
  </script>
```

It results in:

```
cl1.myVar1 closure 1 closure 1
cl2.myVar1 closure 2 closure 2
```

Comment: Ended up not loading the pages with Ajax for a different number of reasons, but this is good to know. But thank you so much!